# excel - string validate

Tags: excel, parsing, excel-formula

I have strings which I need to validate such as

```
'AB01MCD10werdfGhjklOP01DEF03124'
```

It starts with `AB`, followed by a two character number, which tells us how many characters follow for 'AB'(In this case it is `01`, just 1 character that is M). It should be followed by `CD`, again with the same behaviour, followed by `OP`, which is optional ie the `OP` group may or may not be present. Finally it should end with the `EF` gr

1. String starts with 'AB', mandatory
2. Followed by 'CD' again mandatory
3. Followed by 'OP' which is optional
4. Followed by 'EF', mandatory

I want to validate the string in A1 and put the validation result in B1.

If the validation is success, B1 should have *Validation Success*, otherwise *Error:Expected 'CD', but found 'blah*.

Please let me know the best way to do this - is it using a formula or a macro?

Comment: IMO a user defined function would work best here.

Comment: Can you post a few examples of failures and what you'd expect to see?

Comment: This is best handled via a RegExp UDF (Kyle's approach) but some further examples would be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `RegExp`  validates a string that:

1. Starts with *AB*, then a 2 digit number that sets the number of *alphabetical* characters to follow
2. Followed by *CD*, then a 2 digit number that sets the number of *alphabetical* characters to follow
3. Optional *OP* which if it exists also has 2 digit number that sets the number of *alphabetical* characters to follow
4. Followed by *EF*, then a 2 digit number that sets the number of *numerical* characters to follow

*If this is what you wanted for your strings then I will tweak the `Len` section to flag where the test breaks (ie the Error:Expected 'CD'). Although I note **you could have up to 4 potential issues with a string** rather than the singular issue in your example*).

If you are happy with any character (which the code from Chris will accept) rather than the alphabetical and numeric example you gave then the `RegExp` can be simplified.

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print Validator("AB01MCD10werdfGhjklOP01DEF03124") ' TRUE with optionalOP
    Debug.Print Validator("AB01MCD10werdfGhjklEF03124")      ' TRUE without optional OP
    Debug.Print Validator("AB01MCD10weardfGhjklOP01DEF03124")  ' fail as CD string is too long
End Sub

Function Validator(strIn As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim objRegexM As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Pattern = "AB(\d{2})([a-z]+)CD(\d{2})([a-z]+)((?=OP)OP(\d{2})([a-z]+)){0,1}EF(\d{2})(\d+)"
        .ignoreCase = True
        If .Test(strIn) Then
            Set objRegexM = .Execute(strIn)
            With objRegexM(0)
                Validator = Len(.submatches(1)) = CLng(.submatches(0)) And Len(.submatches(3)) = CLng(.submatches(2)) And Len(.submatches(6)) = CLng(.submatches(5)) And Len(.submatches(8)) = CLng(.submatches(7))
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Much neater than mine, but I'd prefer `.Pattern = "AB(\d{2})([a-zA-Z]+)CD(\d{2})([a-zA-Z]+)((?=OP)OP(\d{2})([a-zA-Z]+)){0,1}EF(\d{2})(\d+)"` with `.IgnoreCase=False` that way, the parameters must be in capitals. Currently `ab01Mcd10werdfGhjklop01Def03124` is valid

Comment: @Kyle That is a fair point. Once we hear back from the OP re the constraints if any re alphabetical and numerical sub-strings then I will accomodate this

Comment: Thanks. That is awesome. Actually OP, AB, CD ahould all be in uppercase. Also OP follows the same pattern as others. It is an optional occurence, as indicate in the above example - AB01MCD10werdfGhjklEF03124.

Comment: @Suresh Thx :) - so this is what you wanted? I will update to prevent lower case AB/OP etc if you want

Comment: Also OP follows the same pattern as others, ie first two chars should be number, following could be either number or alphabets.

Comment: @brettdj.  Thanks. This is more than I need. :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `EF` term also being of the form `EFnn<n characters>`, try this

```
Function CheckString(r As Range) As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim substr As String
    Dim v As Long

    str = r.Value

    If Left$(str, 2) = "AB" Then
        str = Mid$(str, 3)
        substr = Left$(str, 2)
        str = Mid$(str, 3)
        If IsNumeric(substr) Then
            v = Val(substr)
            str = Mid$(str, v + 1)
            ' CD
            If Left$(str, 2) = "CD" Then
                str = Mid$(str, 3)
                substr = Left$(str, 2)
                str = Mid$(str, 3)
                If IsNumeric(substr) Then
                    v = Val(substr)
                    str = Mid$(str, v + 1)

                    ' OP or EF
                    If Left$(str, 2) = "OP" Then
                        str = Mid$(str, 3)
                        substr = Left$(str, 2)
                        str = Mid$(str, 3)
                        If IsNumeric(substr) Then
                            v = Val(substr)
                            str = Mid$(str, v + 1)

                            ' EF
                            If Left$(str, 2) = "EF" Then
                                str = Mid$(str, 3)
                                substr = Left$(str, 2)
                                str = Mid$(str, 3)
                                If IsNumeric(substr) Then
                                    v = Val(substr)
                                    If Len(str) = v Then
                                        CheckString = "Validation Success"
                                    Else
                                        ' No more after EF
                                        CheckString = "Error: Expecting " & v & " characters after EF"
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    ' number follows EF
                                    CheckString = "Error: Expected number following EF"
                                End If
                            Else
                                CheckString = "Error: Expecting EF"
                            End If
                        Else
                            ' number follows CD
                            CheckString = "Error: Expected number following CD"
                        End If

                    ' EF
                    ElseIf Left$(str, 2) = "EF" Then
                        str = Mid$(str, 3)
                        substr = Left$(str, 2)
                        str = Mid$(str, 3)
                        If IsNumeric(substr) Then
                            v = Val(substr)
                            If Len(str) = v Then
                                CheckString = "Validation Success"
                            Else
                                ' No more after EF
                                CheckString = "Error: Expecting " & v & " characters after EF"
                            End If
                        Else
                            ' number follows EF
                            CheckString = "Error: Expected number following EF"
                        End If
                    Else
                        CheckString = "Error: Expecting EF"
                    End If

                Else
                    ' number follows CD
                    CheckString = "Error: Expected number following CD"
                End If
            Else
                ' Begin with "CD"
                CheckString = "Error: Expected CD"
            End If
        Else
            ' number follows AB
            CheckString = "Error: Expected number following AB"
        End If
    Else
        ' Begin with "AB"
        CheckString = "Error: Expected AB"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: +1 for nifty indenting and managing to get 13 mid function in ;)

Comment: Your function allows numeric characters in between the specified number and the next parameter, it also allows letters following EF. I think we need a bit more clarification from the op

Comment: This is too long an approach for parsing

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function that will do the job for you. But if you have more than AB/CD/EF then you will have to modify the code accordingly

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim A1 As String
Dim B1 As String

A1 = "AB01MCD10werdfGhjklOP01DEF03124"
B1 = CodeValidate(A1)

MsgBox B1

End Sub



Function CodeValidate(ByVal TXT As String) As String
    Dim AB As Boolean
    Dim CD As Boolean
    Dim EF As Boolean
    Dim OP As Boolean

    Dim NextCounter As Integer
    Dim Buffer As String

    Dim result As String


    For i = 1 To Len(TXT)
        Buffer = Buffer & Mid(TXT, i, 1)
        If Len(Buffer) = 2 Then
        '============
            Select Case Buffer
            Case "AB"
                If AB = False And CD = False And EF = False Then
                    AB = True
                    NextCounter = Val(Mid(TXT, i + 1, 2))
                    i = i + 2 + NextCounter
                    Buffer = ""
                Else
                    result = "Error: Duplicate [AB] found at position " & i & "."
                    Exit For
                End If
            Case "CD"
                If AB = True And CD = False And EF = False Then
                    CD = True
                    NextCounter = Val(Mid(TXT, i + 1, 2))
                    i = i + 2 + NextCounter
                    Buffer = ""
                Else
                    result = "Error: Duplicate [CD] found at position " & i & "."
                    Exit For
                End If
            Case "EF"
                If AB = True And CD = True And EF = False Then
                    EF = True
                    NextCounter = Val(Mid(TXT, i + 1, 2))
                    i = i + 2 + NextCounter
                    Buffer = ""
                Else
                    result = "Error: Duplicate [EF] found at position " & i & "."
                    Exit For
                End If
            Case "OP"
                If OP = False Then
                    OP = True
                    NextCounter = Val(Mid(TXT, i + 1, 2))
                    i = i + 2 + NextCounter
                    Buffer = ""
                Else
                    result = "Error: Duplicate [OP] found at position " & i & "."
                    Exit For
                End If
            Case Else
                If AB = False Then
                    result = "Error: Expecting [AB] but found [" & Buffer & "] at position " & i & "."
                    Exit For
                ElseIf AB = True And CD = False Then
                    result = "Error: Expecting [CD] but found [" & Buffer & "] at position " & i & "."
                    Exit For
                ElseIf AB = True And CD = True And EF = False Then
                    result = "Error: Expecting [EF] but found [" & Buffer & "] at position " & i & "."
                    Exit For
                End If
            End Select
        '============
        End If
    Next

    If result = "" Then
        result = "Validation Success"
    End If

    CodeValidate = result

End Function
```

Comment: Passes `EF` without number and that many characters following.  Granted, OP is unclear on this, but the example seems to suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first crack, there may be better way, regular expressions aren't my thing, but it works for the example:

```
Public Function ValString(strInput As String) As String

    Static regEx As Object
    Dim x As Long
    Dim temp$
    Dim matches As Object

    If regEx Is Nothing Then Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With regEx
        .Pattern = "^AB([0-9]{2})([A-Za-z]{" & Val(Mid(strInput, InStr(1, strInput, "AB") + 2, 2)) & "})CD([0-9]{2})([A-Za-z]{" & Val(Mid(strInput, InStr(1, strInput, "CD") + 2, 2)) & "})(OP([0-9]{2})[A-Za-z]+EF[0-9]+|EF[0-9]+)$"
        Set matches = .Execute(strInput)
        If .Test(strInput) Then
            ValString = "Validation Success"
            Exit Function
        Else
            .Pattern = "(AB|CD|EF)"
            .Global = True
            Set matches = .Execute(strInput)
            If matches.Count > 0 Then
                temp$ = "ABCDEF"
                For x = 0 To matches.Count - 1
                    temp$ = Replace(temp$, matches(x), vbNullString)
                    ValString = ValString & ",'" & matches(x) & "'"
                Next x
                If Len(temp$) > 1 Then
                    ValString = "Error:Expected '" & temp$ & "', Found " & Right(ValString, Len(ValString) - 1)
                Else
                    ValString = "Error:Paramaters Found, invalid string"
                End If
            Else
                ValString = "Error:Expected 'CD', Found nothing"
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

As per Chris's suggestion, edited to enforce 2 digits following AB and CD dictating the length of the following characters

If Characters OP follows the same pattern then you can use:

```
.Pattern = "^AB([0-9]{2})([A-Za-z]{" & Val(Mid(strInput, InStr(1, strInput, "AB") + 2, 2)) & "})CD([0-9]{2})([A-Za-z]{" & Val(Mid(strInput, InStr(1, strInput, "CD") + 2, 2)) & "})(OP([0-9]{2})([A-Za-z]{" & Val(Mid(strInput, InStr(1, strInput, "OP") + 2, 2)) & "})EF[0-9]+|EF[0-9]+)$"
```

As above but EF also follows the same pattern but just for numbers:

```
.Pattern = "^AB([0-9]{2})([A-Za-z]{" & Val(Mid(strInput, InStr(1, strInput, "AB") + 2, 2)) & "})CD([0-9]{2})([A-Za-z]{" & Val(Mid(strInput, InStr(1, strInput, "CD") + 2, 2)) & "})(OP([0-9]{2})([A-Za-z]{" & Val(Mid(strInput, InStr(1, strInput, "OP") + 2, 2)) & "})(EF[0-9]{2})([0-9]{" & Val(Mid(strInput, InStr(1, strInput, "EF") + 2, 2)) & "})|(EF[0-9]{2})([0-9]{" & Val(Mid(strInput, InStr(1, strInput, "EF") + 2, 2)) & "}))$"
```

Comment: This doesn't check for the correct number of characters between codes

Comment: Having re-read the question, I'm still not sure that that is a requirement, guess the OP will let us know.

Comment: what part of `followed by a two character number, which tells us how many characters follow` isn't clear?

Comment: I thought you were referring to the number matching the number characters following it

Comment: To clarify: `AC01` requires 1 character after `AB01` and before `CD`.  Yours passes with 1 or more characters

Comment: No, the EF is intentional, it doesn't follow the same format since all the following characters are numbers, that's why I asked for a few more examples. The OP also doesn't state whether OP should also follow the format (although I suspect it should). If they should the'yre easily added